# in flex my button appears in the line below a formitem

Tags: apache-flex, forms, layout, button, mxml

in flex my button appears in the line below a formitem. is there any other way of adding in a button so that it will appear on the same level as the rest of the formitem? There does not seem to be a button property on the formitem code. Attached is an example of a formitem and the code for a button underneath. Any suggestions most welcome, thank you.

```
<ch:FormItem label="Gym Dosier Type:" >
<pss:dossierFinder id="gymOriginFinder" displayLabel="true"
allowMultipleSelection="false"
autoContactServer="true"
initialAccountClass="{AccountClassConstants.gym}"  
 accountClassEnabled="false"
initialMultigym="{gymInterdossierchinder.model.selectedItem.code}"
initialgymsource="{gymsource.model.selectedItem.internalCode}"/>
<mx:Button id = "addLineButton" icon="{addIcon}" toolTip="Add new gym member"                click="{addPack(event)}" enabled="true"/>
</ch:FormItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear if the <ch:FormItem/> is your own separate component or just extends mx:FormItem, but in latter case, uou can set the **direction** parameter of the **FormItem** component to **horizontal**.